# Estimating a distribution from sums of samples

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, exponential-distribution

I'm trying to figure out the parameters of a distribution from real data, but I only get their sums and counts.  For either exponential or normal distributions.

So, I'll get the sum of 27 samples, paired with the number 27, and then the sum of 5 samples, paired with the number 5, etc.  So sample $ S_1 = \Sigma_{i=1}^{27} s_i, C_1 = 27 $ and $S_2 = \Sigma_{i=1}^{5} s_i, C_2 = 5$, etc.

My first thought was to replicate means for each, but it seems a bit dumb.

Is there a smarter way?  I was "good at math" some time ago, so I'm happy to do some reading to sort out details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the exponential distribution, you can use ML estimator for $\lambda$; but for the normal, you can't estimate $\sigma$ with only count and sum.

Comment: Are the components ($s_i$) independent and identically distributed? How do you know they're exponential and normal, respectively?

Comment: Are $S_1$ and $S_2$ separate samples from the _same_ normal distribution, or are they totally separate distributions? If totally separate, you indeed have no hope at estimating $\sigma$ (without further strong assumptions), but if you have 32 samples from the _same_ normal distribution and you just only observe aggregated parts like this, assuming the division into parts is uniformly random, then you can definitely do that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. $S_1,S_2$ are both separate samples of the same thing. As an example (the actual domain is computer performance measurement, and I don't want to distract from the conversation), say they're times for a car around a track, where we have a moody timekeeper that only says "it took you 5:22 for 8 laps", where this guy randomly and independently selects the number of laps he times our car for.  I don't care about his moods, I just want to know how fast the car is.

Comment: Let's take the type of distribution (exp, normal) as given by an oracle.

Comment: Elapsed times cannot be normal. Your oracle is broken.

Comment: .. is this about the example or something fundamental in sums?

Comment: The normal distribution assigns non-zero probability to negative values. Elapsed times are strictly positive so cannot really be normal. In a more practical vein, elapsed times are usually pretty right skew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be something like a self-study exercise so I won't presently give a full solution to every part but I will get you a fair way along.

Basic results on expectations and variances:

$\qquad$1. $ E(\sum_i s_i) = \sum_i E(s_i)$

$\qquad$2. $ \text{Var}(\sum_i s_i) = \sum_i \text{Var}(s_i), \:$ for independent variates

For iid exponentials with mean $\mu$, for given $C_j$, $S_j$ has population mean $C_j\, \mu$ and $S_j/C_j = \overline{s}$ has population mean $\mu$. You could estimate $\mu$ from a single $(S,C)$ pair. If you have more than one of them, you will want to weight them appropriately in a weighted average.

For iid normals with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, for given $C_j$, $S_j$ has population mean $C_j\, \mu$ and $S_j/C_j = \overline{s}$ has population mean $\mu$. The variance of $S_j$ is $C_j\, \sigma^2$, and the variance of $\bar{s}$ is $\sigma^2/C_j$. If you only have $S$ and $C$ values available to you, you'll require more than one of them to estimate $\sigma$.

Usually, you'd solve problems like this via the method of [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation), rather than just by [equating moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_%28statistics%29), but in these two cases, that turns out to be essentially the same thing.